# 'where' in with duplicates or 'select distinct' - performance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to return some results basing on subquery results and I was wondering what would be faster - having subquery results be distinct or where in clause having duplicates? 
Example

```
select * 
from some_table 
where my_column in (select /* distinct? */ my_column from some_table_2)
```

If

```
-- subquery
select /*distinct?*/ my_column from some_table_2;
```

This would return something like:

```
  | MY_COLUMN
1 | 25
2 | 25
3 | 54
...
```

This example may not make sense but it presents my point.

Answer (score 3):

There is no benefit to putting `distinct` in the subquery for `in`.  An `in` does what is called a "semi-join".  This stops at the first matching row.

Oracle probably ignores the `select distinct`.  Other databases might actually implement it.

If you care about performance, try both these versions:

```
select t.* 
from some_table t
where my_column in (select my_column from some_table_2)
```

and

```
select t.*
from some_table t
where exists (select 1 from some_table_2 t2 where t2.my_column = t.my_column);
```

This version can take advantage of an index on `some_table_2(my_column)`.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, these 2 statements are exactly the same. Oracle re-writes the first on into the second one ( Tested on a 11.2g here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a9b0/2 and on Oracle Live SQL for the second ) the plan hash value are the same

Comment: @LauDec . . . I imagine that would be dependent on the available indexes.  There are situations where you would not want the same execution plan, and Oracle has a pretty smart optimizer.